# Ideal login / password / signup page for editing account

Tags: website-design, login, signup-signon

I am trying to design a simple login and password signin dialog box that pops in on the same page.

I don't want the user to navigate AWAY from the page to login.

I am looking for examples of sites that successfully implement this.

Placement, graphics, type of controls.
Visually is it best to show a 'keyhole' tab, once clicked the sign up / sign in page appears?

I personally am heading to that type of setup, but have not found other sites implementing this type of setup (I am sure there are, I just am not very good at finding those sites)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much like the current [Gist](http://gist.com/) login which matches your needs. You click the login button which is clearly identifiable at the top in a crisp cleanly designed page and the popup appears around it. You use the same button to hide it. The popup appears brighter because the rest of the screen darkens slightly - not so much as to throw you - but just enough to make it effective.

I think it's an excellent example in almost every respect!

[image]

[image]

**See also [Break](http://www.break.com/):** which includes options to sign in with facebook

[image]

**[Barnes and Noble](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/)** although this particular design looks like the whole page has faded - including the form itself!

[image]

**[Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/)** which has a nice simple popup appearing

[image]

as well as [The Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/).

Comment: Very nice login, I wonder if there are more sites out there like that (to comapre). Not crazy about the darkening, but yes it is effective.

Comment: @eLouai - I added some more examples to compare with